# How to filter a dictionary when the value of the dictionary is a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I hope you can help me.

I have a dictionary with the following structure:

```
inventory = {
    "brand": ["bmw", "audi", "harley davidson"],
    "type": ["car", "car", "motorcycle"],
    "value": [100, 200, 150],
}
```

I wonder if it's possible to filter by brand and by type.

Comment: Can I use pandas?

Comment: yes its possible ... there are many ways to solve this... you should give it a try and come back once you are stuck

Answer (score 2):

This is a more pythonic way. With no external libraries. If you work with data often, it's also good to get acquainted to a functional style of programming. It's a clean way to write **idempotent** operations over data.

```py
import functools

inventory = {
    "brand": ["bmw", "audi", "harley davidson"],
    "type": ["car", "car", "motorcycle"],
    "value": [100, 200, 150],
}

def is_car(i):
  return inventory["type"][i] == 'car' 

cars_total_value = functools.reduce(
    lambda total, v: total + v[1] if is_car(v[0]) else total,
    enumerate(inventory["value"]),
    0
)

print('Cars total value: %.2f' % cars_total_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is quickly becoming (became?) the premium CSV parsing and tabular filtering package in the world of Python.  I won't try to guess how you read your CSV in, but starting the from the dictionary, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

inventory = {
    "brand": ["bmw", "audi", "harley davidson"],
    "type": ["car", "car", "motorcycle"],
    "value": [100, 200, 150],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(inventory)
df.query('type == "car"')
```

which prints

```
  brand type  value
0   bmw  car    100
1  audi  car    200
```

In the future, consider creating a dataframe directly from the CSV file using [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

#### common

```py
car_sum_res = 0
for index, t in enumerate(inventory['type']):
    if t == 'car':
        car_sum_res += inventory['value'][index]
print(car_sum_res)
```

#### pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

inventory = {
    "brand": ["bmw", "audi", "harley davidson"],
    "type": ["car", "car", "motorcycle"],
    "value": [100, 200, 150],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(inventory)
car_sum_res = df.loc[df['type'] == 'car', 'value'].sum()
print(car_sum_res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out pandas for easy dataframe manipulation.

```
import pandas as pd

inventory = {
    "brand": ["bmw", "audi", "harley davidson"],
    "type": ["car", "car", "motorcycle"],
    "value": [100, 200, 150],
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(inventory)

print(df)

[Output]
             brand        type  value
0              bmw         car    100
1             audi         car    200
2  harley davidson  motorcycle    150
```

Once in a dataframe, manipulating the data is easy, but you'll likely need to research specific functions.

```
df['value'].sum()
450

df['value'].where(df['type'] == 'car').sum().astype(int)
300
```

(You may have to do some typecasting to get your desired result.)
As an added bonus, if your data is in an Excel spreadsheet, pandas can read it directly:

```
df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')
```

(This is a simple example; pandas has lots of options.)